# Telegram Bot PHP keyboard doesn't works

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a problem to creating a custom keyboard for my telegram bot.

Simply, it doesn't works and I don't know the reason...

This is my code:

```
<?
$botToken = "*****";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

$update = file_get_contents('php://input');
$update = json_decode($update, TRUE);

$chatId = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$message = $update["message"]["text"];
$telegramusername = $update["message"]["from"]["username"];
$message_id = $update["message"]["message_id"];
$message_name = $update["message"]["chat"]["first_name"];


switch($message)
{
case "ciao":
funzioneCiao($chatId);
break;
case "youtube":
TastieraInline($chatId);
break;
default:
TastieraMenuPrincipale($chatId);
break;
}

function inviaMessaggio($chatId, $messaggio)
{
    $url = "$GLOBALS[website]/sendMessage?chat_id=$chatId&parse_mode=HTML&text=".urlencode($messaggio);
    file_get_contents($url);
}

function funzioneCiao($chatId)
{
    $messaggio = "ciao";
inviaMessaggio($chatId, $messaggio);
}



function TastieraMenuPrincipale($chatId)
{
    $messaggio = "ciaaaao";
    $tastiera = '&reply_markup={"keyboard":[["Menu Principale"],["Developer"]]}';
    $url = "$GLOBALS[website]"."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&parse_mode=HTML&text=".$messaggio.$tastiera;
    file_get_contents($url);

}

function TastieraInline($chatId)
{
    $message = "Iscriviti subito";
    $tastiera = '&reply_markup={"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"SEGUIMI!","url":"http://www.youtube.com"}]]}';
    $url = $GLOBALS[website].'/sendMessage?chat_id='.$chatId.'&parse_mod=HTML&text='.$message.$tastiera;
    file_get_contents($url);
}
?>
```

Functions: "funzioneCiao($chatId);" and "inviaMessaggio($chatId, $messaggio)" works but,
"TastieraMenuPrincipale($chatId)" and "TastieraInLine($ChatId)" doesn't works.

I'm a beginner in PHP so I have a lot difficult...

Thank you.

Comment: You shot display you Bot token. It can be misused. You can use any random letters in place of that.

Comment: It is an example it is not my real Bot ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the code, it works perfectly...

[image]

Comment: Uhm I tried again but it doesn't works with me ....
I'm using a free hosting web to use my bot but doesn't works... can you  help me?

Comment: I tested using url (https://api.telegram......) and it works. So the possible problems are two:

" and ' gives problems or my freewebhosting can't do this

Comment: This is the complete code...
Now the only thing that is not working is the API KEY, because I deleted the bot...
Can you contact me in pvt? alessandrosiveri@gmail.com

Comment: Then you should make another bot with @BotFather and test the code again

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you use CURL instead of `file_get_contents();` ?!

just write this function into your code then call it after getting new updates :

```
function makeHTTPRequest($method, $types = []){
    $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$botToken.'/'.$method;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($types));
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch)){
        var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    } else {
        return json_decode($res);
    }
}
```

make sure CURL is activated on your hosting server!